# How to group-by a collection that is already grouped by in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a collection of maps

```
(def a '({:id 9345 :value 3 :type "orange"}
         {:id 2945 :value 2 :type "orange"}
         {:id 145 :value 3 :type "orange"}
         {:id 2745 :value 6 :type "apple"}
         {:id 2345 :value 6 :type "apple"}))
```

I want to group this first by value, followed by type.

My output should look like:

```
{
    :orange [{
        :value 3,
        :id [9345, 145]
    }, {
        :value 2,
        :id [2935]
    }], 
    :apple [{
        :value 6,
        :id [2745, 2345]
    }]
}
```

How would I do this in Clojure? Appreciate your answers.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Here is what I had so far:

```
(defn by-type-key [data]
  (group-by #(get % "type") data))

(reduce-kv
  (fn [m k v] (assoc m k (reduce-kv
                           (fn [sm sk sv] (assoc sm sk (into [] (map #(:id %) sv))))
                           {}
                           (group-by :value (map #(dissoc % :type) v)))))
  {}
  (by-type-key a))
```

Output:

```
=> {"orange" {3 [9345 145], 2 [2945]}, "apple" {6 [2745 2345], 3 [125]}}
```

I just couldnt figure out how to proceed next...

Comment: @cfrick Edited my original post with whatever solution I had so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the transform in two stages (using reduce):

- the first to collect the values
- the second for formating

The following code solves your problem:

```
(def a '({:id 9345 :value 3 :type "orange"}
         {:id 2945 :value 2 :type "orange"}
         {:id 145 :value 3 :type "orange"}
         {:id 2745 :value 6 :type "apple"}
         {:id 2345 :value 6 :type "apple"}))

(defn standardise [m]
  (->> m
       ;; first stage
       (reduce (fn [out {:keys [type value id]}]
                 (update-in out [type value] (fnil #(conj % id) [])))
               {})
       ;; second stage
       (reduce-kv (fn [out k v]
                    (assoc out (keyword k)
                           (reduce-kv (fn [out value id]
                                        (conj out {:value value
                                                   :id id}))
                                      []
                                      v)))
                  {})))

(standardise a)
;; => {:orange [{:value 3, :id [9345 145]} 
;;              {:value 2, :id [2945]}], 
;;     :apple [{:value 6, :id [2745 2345]}]}
```

the output of the first stage is:

```
(reduce (fn [out {:keys [type value id]}]
             (update-in out [type value] (fnil #(conj % id) [])))
        {}
        a)
;;=> {"orange" {3 [9345 145], 2 [2945]}, "apple" {6 [2745 2345]}}
```

Comment: @yuri-steinschreiber's solution for the first stage is probably what i would go with as it better conveys what is being done

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are a bit inconsistent (or rather irregular) - you use `:type` values as keywords in the result, but the rest of the keywords are carried through. Maybe that's what you must do to satisfy some external formats - otherwise you need to either use the same approach as with `:type` through, or add a new keyword to the result, like `:group` or `:rows` and keep the original keywords intact. I will assume the former approach for the moment (but see below, I will get to the shape as you want it,) so the final shape of data is like

```
{:orange
     {:3 [9345 145],
      :2 [2945]},
 :apple
     {:6 [2745 2345]}
}
```

There is more than one way of getting there, here's the gist of one:

```
(group-by (juxt :type :value) a)
```

The result:

```
{["orange" 3] [{:id 9345, :value 3, :type "orange"} {:id  145, :value 3, :type "orange"}],
 ["orange" 2] [{:id 2945, :value 2, :type "orange"}],
 ["apple" 6] [{:id 2745, :value 6, :type "apple"} {:id 2345, :value 6, :type "apple"}]}
```

Now all rows in your collection are grouped by the keys you need. From this, you can go and get the shape you want, say to get to the shape above you can do

```
(reduce 
 (fn [m [k v]]
    (let [ks (map (comp keyword str) k)]
      (assoc-in m ks
                (map :id v))))
 {}
 (group-by (juxt :type :value) a))
```

The basic idea is to get the rows grouped by the key sequence (and that's what `group-by` and `juxt` do,) and then combine `reduce` and `assoc-in` or `update-in` to beat the result into place.

To get exactly the shape you described:

```
(reduce
 (fn [m [k v]]
   (let [type (keyword (first k))
         value (second k)
         ids (map :id v)]
     (update-in m [type]
                #(conj % {:value value :id ids}))))
 {}
 (group-by (juxt :type :value) a))
```

It's a bit noisy, and it might be harder to see the forest for the trees - that's why I simplified the shape, to highlight the main idea. The more regular your shapes are, the shorter and more regular your functions become - so if you have control over it, try to make it simpler for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to use the built-in function `group-by`.  See http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/group-by